# Button is clicked but no further action in appium with selenium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Button click is not working in **Selenium-Appium-android chrome browser**.
I wrote a automation script in **selenium**. It is working on **all desktop browsers** (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari). But it is **not** working in android **chrome browser**.

**Configuration details:**

> Selenium/java drivers: 2.53.0 (also tried with latest version 3.0)
>   appium version: 1.4.16.1
>   Mobile: 
>   Samsung Galaxy J2 5.1.1
>   Android verion: 5.1.1. 
>   Chrome version (mobile): 52.0.2743.98
>   appium java client: 4.1.1; also tried using older clients.

Using javascript executer i can able to highlight it. When click method is executed it is blinking. But subsequent action for the button click is not happening. Tried with all locators. Keys.Enter, Keys.Return, clicked using Javascript executer. Nothing happened.

Below is the page source. There is a button in the website with the button caption as "More...".

```js
div class="search-results-more margin-btm-20">
a id="search-more" class="btn btn-submit btn-dark" href="javascript:void(0)">More...</a>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As this button has ID so I would recommend find elements using ID. Before clicking the button make sure you are in web view context.

```
Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles(); // This will return something like 'NATIVE_APP', 'WEBVIEW_1', ...

        // make sure we have something other than the native context
        // assertThat(contexts.size(), greaterThan(1));
        for (String context : contexts) {
            // System.out.println(contexts);
            if (!context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {
                driver.context((String) contexts.toArray()[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

driver.findElement(By.id("search-more")).click();
```

Comment: Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles(); The method getContextHandles() is undefined for the type WebDriver. how to resolve this error.

Comment: Thank you Suman. I changed the context using the below code. But still I'm not able to click the "more..." button.

Set<String> contexts = ((AndroidDriver) driver).getContextHandles();
     for (String context : contexts) {
             System.out.println("contexts: " + contexts);
            if (!context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {
                ((AndroidDriver) driver).context((String)contexts.toArray()[1]);
                break;
            }
           
        }

the above code printed as "contexts: [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_1]".

Comment: Did you check the context before clicking the element? When you inspect using appium inspector what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Cast your driver to appium driver. I am using the below -

```
public AppiumDriver<?> driver;
```